# Asp.net mvc return model with Ienumerable

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, linq-to-sql, c#-4.0, model

I am having a problem of the return type IEnumerable<> of the model which I try to better understand:

I am having a Model view:

```
public class Photoview
{
    public int IdPhoto { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public string Nom { get; set; }
    public int Category { get; set; }
    public string Lien { get; set; }
    public bool Actif { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

and a model, which gets data from the database:

```
    public IEnumerable<Photoview> GetAllPhotos()
    {
        var a = from o in _ajAentities.Photos
                select o;

        return a.ToList();
    }
```

However, I am having a compile error :cannot convert type Generic.List to

The table of the database is:

```
id_photo    int         Unchecked
date    smalldatetime   Checked
nom         nvarchar(250)   Checked
categorie   int         Checked
lien    nvarchar(250)   Checked
actif   bit         Checked
description nvarchar(800)   Checked
```

My question is: How would I make it possible to return the Linq query of GetAllPhotos() as IEnumerable<> type ?

Thanks

Comment: try a.ToList<Photoview>(); 
P.S your didn't write the entire error message

Comment: Hi keshav, thanks for your answer, I try out a.ToList<Photoview>(); error: cannot convert instance argument type 'System.Linq.Iquerable<AJA.Models.DB.Photo> to System.Linq.IEnumerable<AJA.Models.ViewModel.PhotoView>

Comment: What I noticed is that if I change from IEnumerable<Photoview> to IEnumerable<Photo> of the function, the return type is ok, however, I want it to tight with my Modelview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the `_ajAentities.Photos` is of type `IEnumerable<Models.DB.Photo>` and yet you are trying to return an `IEnumerable<Photoview>` from your method.

So the first possibility is to fix your return type to match that of your database entity:

```
public IEnumerable<Photo> GetAllPhotos()
{
    var a = 
        from o in _ajAentities.Photos
        select o;
    return a.ToList();
}
```

The second possibility is to map between the two types:

```
public IEnumerable<Photoview> GetAllPhotos()
{
    var a = 
        from o in _ajAentities.Photos
        select new Photoview
        {
            IdPhoto = o.Id,
            Date = o.Date,
            Nom = o.Nom,
            ....
        };

    return a.ToList();
}
```

You might also take a look at [AutoMapper](http://automapper.org/) to perform the mapping between your domain models and your view models.

Comment: Hi Darin, the second option is what I used to use. However, I find out that the constraint is that when I change the ModelView, there is need to change the Model as well, as the mapping of the properties change too, but yes, it is working sure. for the first possibility, if putting IEnumerable<Photo> as return type of the method, we need to put @model IEnumerable<AJA.Models.DB.Photo> in the View do we ?, If so, as I have heard somewhere saying that it is no good to tight the View directly to the DB model, is it good way to proceed it ? what is your recommendation ? Thanks

Comment: The recommended is to use a view model. And then map between your Photo domain model and the Photoview view model which will be used by the view. You could do this mapping either by hand or using a tool such as AutoMapper. And yes, if your domain model changes, your view model will need to reflect this change. The view model is a projection of one or more domain models for a given view.

Comment: Hi Darin, I will have a close look about autoMapper. As it seems to be the answer. Thanks all

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var a = (IEnumerable<Object>)
        from o in _ajAentities.Photos
        select o;
```

It casts the `IQueryable` to `IEnumerable` returned from Linq. Do no use the `.ToList()` because you're converting it to `List<object>` type collection. Just return the variable.